# Gorenstein ring and projective module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, gorenstein

I am new to this topic and would appreciate little explanation.

Def: A commutative, unital ring $A$ is a cubic ring if $A$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module  of rank $3$.

Def : A cubic ring $A$ is called Gorenstein if the $A$-module $Hom(A, \mathbb{Z})$ is projective.

I am a bit confused here. Every module over a PID is projective. Also for any $A$-module $M$ we have $Hom_{A}(A, M)\cong M$, so in particular $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, A)\cong A$ but $A$ is a free module hence projective, but then $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, A)$ must be projective as well, or am I mixing up something?

Comment: *Every module over a PID is projective.* That isn't true. Some word left out, perhaps?

Comment: @user26857: I have corrected the definition. It should be $A$-module $Hom(A,\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @user26857 it is not specified. The definition comes from Gross ''FOURIER COEFFICIENTS OF MODULAR FORMS ON G2'' http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gross/preprints/rez.pdf p.13

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},A)\cong A$ as $A$ modules, but this is not true in general for the $A$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I guess the Hom is over $\mathbb{Z}$ which a canonical module for the ring $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Not every abelian group Is projective ,take nonzero torsion group for example